# Как правильно создать типизированный DataSet?

Tags: c#, sql, .net, ado.net

Типизированный DataSet- это DataSet в котором заведомо известны все DataTable и обращаться к ним можно по имени. В свою очередь DataTable тоже известны и можно получать доступ к полям без литералов и без приведения к конкретному типу. Т.е работа становится похоже на работу с классом у которого есть поля.

Подскажите, как правильно это делается? Какие возможны подводные камни(Нет ли особенностей наполнения через DataAdapter.Fill? или десериализации)? Что лучше переопределять в своих расширенных классах?

Если такое возможно, то не помешал бы примерчик с типизированным DataSet, где имеется 2 таблицы, которые имеют отношение по какому-то полю.

Хочется что-то типа такого сделать:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt710792.aspx

Но опять же, там не пишут про подводные камни и про то, что лучше переопределить в расширенных классах.

Comment: ИМХО, всегда когда, есть возможность, нужно использовать типизизированный DS, пусть за Вас работает Microsoft. Чтобы, ответить на Ваши вопросы о подводных камнях - нужны подробности, что Вы хотите.

Comment: ИМХО, правильно строить типизированный DS нужно c помощью "дизайнера", встроенного в VisualStudio. С его помощью можно, предварительно приконектившись к базе данных, сформировать нужную подсхемы и дополнить ее, если нужно, элементами, которых нет в исходной базе данных. Очевидно, что более надежный способ обращаться к методам и объектам сгенериованных автоматически классов, чем вызывать их  по именам. Это есть все по ссылке на msdn, которую Вы привели.

Comment: Точно также встроенный дизайнер позволяет Вам легко создавать и дополнять нужными методами адаптеры, однако нужно помнить, что адаптеры могут корректно работать только с запросами, которые содержат все колонки таблицы, к которой он привязан. Если Вам нужно  работать с подмножестовм, то наиболее простой способ сделать дополнительную фиктивную таблицу (view) со своим адатером. Это тоже все описано в MSDN.

Comment: Подводные камни все те же, которые присущи использованию автоматически сгенированного кода. Есть еще один подводный камень - скорость работы, которая зависит от количества и типа полей, которые адаптер гоняет взад и вперед. Если в таблице есть BLOB поля, котрые редко нужны, а скорость критична, то в это случан с таблицей лучше работать минуя адаптер.

Comment: Я совершенно не понимаю Ваших проблем, пожалуйста расскажите о своей задаче подробнее. Что у Вас вызывает затруднения?

Comment: @АлександрМуксимов, задачи никакой нет. Просто, хочу узнать, как удобно работать с DataSet. Вот типизированный DataSet по сути маскирует все и делает работу, похожей на работу с обычным классом(Т.е не нужно ничего приводить, не нужно помнить что за таблицы у тебя содержаться внутри DataSet, так как включаются подсказки студии.)

Comment: Остались ли у Вас вопросы?  - по моему Вы на них ответили сами: "...типизированный DataSet по сути маскирует все и делает работу..." :)

Comment: @iluxa1810 "как удобно работать с DataSet" - с ним нельзя удобно работать, именно поэтому и придумали LINQ :)